How can I find out more about a cast iron fireback?
How can I find out more about a cast iron fireback?
I saw this fireback in a house in the north of England that dates from the 1660s. The main hall (which dates from the original house) contains an inglenook fireplace which had a fireback of this design.
It's obviously a popular design (google 'Royal Oak cast iron fireback' and you'll see what I mean), the design is probably based on the story of King Charles I hiding in an oak tree in 1651.
My guess is that the design dates back to shortly after the restoration in 1660, is this correct? Or maybe the design only dates from much later? maybe the Victorian period? It seems examples of this are still available, and from what I can tell some are still be made today.
Is there anyway determining when a particular fireback dates from? The house, hallway and fireplace all date from the correct period, but is there anyway of knowing if the fireback really dates from when the house was built, or maybe a later addition?

(this image isn't the actual fireback, but is an identical design)
Update in response to comments - the fireback is in a private home, the current owners only know the construction date from a foundation stone. There are obviously hundreds of these in existence, I'm not expecting precise identification of an individual fireback, I'm more interested in the history of the design itself and any techniques for telling the difference between a 370 year old piece of cast iron and 10 year old piece of cast iron!

Did you ask the owner/management of the house?
